# Measuring EV3 Color Sensor Reflected Light Intensity via leJos

Tags: java, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I have a question:

Via leJos, I want to control my ev3 color sensor which is connected to port 2.

But actually when I looked at the EV3ColorSensor class, I couldn't find any method which I can measure the reflected light intensity of my colorsensor connected port 2.

Or I couldn't understand from the names of methods whether there is such a method which can do what I want.

Could you help me for this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can not test this code at the very moment, but it might need just minimal tweaks:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import lejos.hardware.sensor.EV3ColorSensor;
import lejos.hardware.port.Port;
import lejos.hardware.port.SensorPort;
import lejos.robotics.SampleProvider;

public class ColorSensorTest {

    // Modes and samples are explained in LeJOS wiki:
    // http://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/wiki/Sensor%20Framework/
    private static Port colorSensorPort = SensorPort.S2;
    private static EV3ColorSensor colorSensor;
    private static SampleProvider sampleProvider;
    private static int sampleSize;

    private static float[] getSample() {
        // Initializes the array for holding samples
        float[] sample = new float[sampleSize];

        // Gets the sample an returns it
        sampleProvider.fetchSample(sample, 0);
        return sample;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initializes the sensor & sensor mode
        colorSensor = new EV3ColorSensor(colorSensorPort);
        sampleProvider = colorSensor.getRedMode();
        sampleSize = sampleProvider.sampleSize();

        // Takes some samples and prints them
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            float[] sample = getSample();
            System.out.println("N=" + i + " Sample=" + Arrays.toString(sample));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to set the **RED LED** on using the **setFloodLight** below. It works fine with that.

```
sampleProvider = colorSensor.getRedMode();
colorSensor.setFloodlight(Color.RED);
```